# error QPushButton in a dock widget is inaccessible

Tags: qt

Newbie here, I put a dock widget in a main window, and there is a button in this dock widget panel, now I want to connect, this button with a function defined in the main window, it threw out an error, what should I do? Thanks

```
connect
(
    perfectPanel_->btn_AAA,
    SIGNAL(clicked()),
    this,
    SLOT(on_actionAAA_triggered()),
    Qt::UniqueConnection
);
```

Error message is

```
$PWD/ui_perfectPanel.h: In constructor ‘xixi::xixi()’:
$PWD/ui_perfectPanel.h:71:18: error: ‘QPushButton* Ui_perfectPanel::btn_AAA’ is inaccessible
$PWD/xixi/xixi.cpp:51:25: error: within this context
```

Note that I have already managed to connect this with a toolbar button in the main window (xixi.cpp), it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your dock class, `perfectPanel`, inherits privately from the generated ui class `Ui::perfectPanel`:

```cpp
class perfectPanel : public QWidget, private Ui::perfectPanel
```

You could make that inheritance public, but shouldn't. Instead you should make the signal part of the `perfectPanel` class, and route the internal signal from the button to that external signal:

```
class perfectPanel ... {
...
signals:
    void AAA_clicked();
};

perfectPanel::perfectPanel() {
     setupUi(this);
     connect(btn_AAA, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SIGNAL(AAA_clicked()));
}
```

(And in case you would ask, yes, you can connect 2 signals together).

Then you simply connect the new signal inside your main window class:

```
connect(perfectPanel_, 
    SIGNAL(AAA_clicked()), 
    this,
    SLOT(on_actionAAA_triggered()),
    Qt::UniqueConnection
);
```